# Change tabbar size in xamarin tabbed page template

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have spent 2 days searching for an answer to this and I just can't find the solution. All I am trying to do is change the size of the "Tabbar" in android for the template that uses sliding tabs. I have tried using a custom renderer, styles, setting it programatically and nothing will achieve what I want. I am able to however change the size of the slider, the font and everything else but changing the height of the tabbar in the tabbedpage is seemingly impossible. If anyone has any solutions to this, please feel free to let me know. I can do it if I set up the project outside of Xamarin.forms but I am really trying to keep a good cross platform solution up rather than making multiple for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
public class StyledTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    private Android.Views.View formViewPager = null;
    private TabLayout tabLayout = null;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        this.tabLayout = (TabLayout)this.GetChildAt(1);

        changeTabsFont();
    }

    private void changeTabsFont()
    {
        //Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "fonts/" + Constants.FontStyle);
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)tabLayout.GetChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.ChildCount;
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++)
        {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup)vg.GetChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.ChildCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++)
            {
                Android.Views.View tabViewChild = vgTab.GetChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild is TextView)
                {
                    //((TextView)tabViewChild).Typeface = font;
                    ((TextView)tabViewChild).TextSize = 6;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```